# Rowfilter: AND operand

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dataGridView which I Filter using three textboxes and the .RowFilter function.

It works when I use the OR operand but not with the AND operand.

```
((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "column1 like "
+"'%"+textbox1+"%' AND column1 like '%"+textbox2+"%' AND column1 like '%"+textbox3+"%'";
```

thanks

To make the Quastion clearer:

Column1                         |Column2  |Column3
--------------------------------|---------|

### Sequence some text interrupted  | xxxxxxx |xxxxxxx       <----This row

Sequence and some text Hold     |xxxxxxx  |xxxxxxx     <---Should not be visable

If my query is: Column1 like '%Sequence%' AND Column1 like '%interrupted%'

the result will show both rows instead of the first row which I want only to show

Comment: Are you sure you have matching data available in the table? Can you show the input data  and the expected output?

Comment: If I test it on a datatable AND works fine, so theres likely something wrong with your query

Comment: What is are the values of `textbox1`, `textbox2` and `textbox3`? And what is the value of `column1` you are expecting to match those textboxes?

Comment: Maybe there is something i miss...

Comment: This is my exact query: Column1 like '%Sequence%' AND Column1 like '%Interrupted%'  But the result show every row where colum1 has the string "Sequence".... i want only to show rows who contains "Sequence" AND "Interrupted"

Comment: What is an example **complete** value that you are seeing returned that you didn't expect?

Comment: A single row can contain both "Sequence" and "Interrupted"? If not you need to go back to using OR.

Comment: Yes Column1  can contain for example "Sequence blablblabla interrupted" Another row can contain "Sequence blablablabla Hold" And I only want to see the row if column1 contains both " Sequence " and "iterrupted "

Comment: So what is in the third textbox?

Comment: Sorry! The query is dynamic if i write something in the third textbox i just add that to the query ... + " AND Column1 like '% " + textbox3.text+"%'";

Comment: I don't know what to say, it works for me. See [this LINQPad script](http://share.linqpad.net/w3fckn.linq)

Comment: Ok! Thank you! Now I at least now that my problem is something else, and not the query... I will check my code again

Comment: Okey! I Solved it... quite embarrassing, but i also executed my OR query. Thanks for your help!